# wkhtmltopdf renders Highchart charts with strange borders

Tags: highcharts, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

For the context, My app allows user to download a PDF report file that contains charts generated by Highcharts, we use wicked_pdf and wkhtmltopdf for this. It worked fine previously using an very old Highcharts(v6), recently we decided to upgrade it to the latest version(v11) and we got several bugs, mostly because wkhtmltopdf doesn't work with new Javascript syntax.

We could manage to fix all the these bugs and able to render the charts on the PDF. but somehow all these charts have a weird border surround them and no matter how we try to configure Highcharts, these borders just do not go away, even though the HTML page still renders these charts without the borders

We use wkthmltopdf to convert the html file to pdf

```
wkhtmltopdf sample_report.html report.pdf
```

**This is sample_report.html**
[image: HTML]

**This is report.pdf**
[image: pdf]

Comment: It seems like wkhtmltopdf issue, not the Highcharts itselfs. For downloading charts as a pdf we recommend to use our export server feature. You can find more information here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server ; https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server